# CSS Display Table, any SEO implications?

Tags: seo, css, table

I want to use CSS display table in place of JS for vertical-alignment and equal heights of HTML elements, however I'm not sure if there are any SEO implications of this, will crawlers try and interpret the contents of elements displayed in this way as tabular data or will they ignore it and interpret it as normal content?

Answer (score 3):

If you use CSS for vertical alignment for HTML elements, there is no bad SEO implications.
Moreover, using CSS instead of a JS script is a good practice because you can then delete the JS file from the webpage and getting a better speed loading for the page (better for SEO).

Otherwise, keep in mind that web crawlers see your final HTML.